# Firefox webextension: Save page as html or text

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

With the new firefox webextensions: Is there a way to save the current page (or a part of it) as html (or text) to disk? If not, how are the chances, such an API will be implemented in the future?

I didn't find any suitable API and appreciate any help.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There are probably several ways to do this. The following will get you started. It saves the webpage in the currently focused tab in the active window to the browser's default downloads path. The file name is set to 'samplePage.html' (you can change that by modifying the filename value in the downloads.download() options; or you can remove that field entirely and leave it to the default naming).

You will need to [store icon images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Add_a_button_to_the_toolbar) in your webextension package for the user to be able to click on. Also, be sure to navigate to a webpage you want to save before you try to use the webextension; webextensions are not active on the Firefox about:debugging page.

***manifest:***

```
{
  "name": "SavePage",
  "version":  "1.0",
  "description":  "Clicking browser icon saves page html",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/clickme-48.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "downloads"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/clickme-32.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }       
}
```

***background script:***

```
/* BACKGROUND SCRIPT

Clicking on browser toolbar button saves the webpage in the
current tab to the browser's default downloads path with a
filename of "samplePage.html". The "tabs" and "downloads" 
permissions are required.

*/


browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  var currentUrl = tab.url;

  function onStartedDownload(id) {
    console.log(`Started to download: ${id}`);
  }

  function onFailed(error) {
    console.log(`Something stinks: ${error}`);
  } 

  var startDownload = browser.downloads.download({
    url : currentUrl,
    filename: 'samplePage.html'
  });

  startDownload.then(onStartedDownload, onFailed);
});
```

An alternative approach might be to try to save the webpage to [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage) rather than to disk. I have not explored that option.

These pages may be helpful:

[downloads.download()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download)

[browserAction.onClicked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/onClicked)

There may be security risks in giving a webextension these permissions. You will have to weigh the risks for your own usage pattern.

Comment: Will this save the plain html to disk? Is there a way to get the "Save as full HTML" or "Save as text" behaviours? Thanks!

Comment: @lith - This is kind of an academic exercise. Have you tried using the "Save Page As..." function from the context menu that pops up from a right-click on the page?

Comment: I guess "academic" is a pejorative term in your world. Just because you can't see the use of something doesn't mean there is no use for it. Anyway, thanks for you original answer.

Comment: @lith - No, I didn't mean to imply that there's anything wrong with your question. I was just pointing out that there already is a built-in function for saving a page in text or html. The script I suggested saves the html that is served up from the webpage's url; it doesn't save everything you see when you are browsing a site, incl. what's injected into the page at runtime, such as a map that is displayed based on your current IP address or current prices of products in a webstore. Maybe someone else can suggest how to use a Webextension to save exactly what is displayed, including as text.

Comment: Yes, there is a built-in function and with a XUL-based firefox I can call that but AFAIK I cannot call it from a webextension, can I?